# Syntax error while updating the Database

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I need to update new person in my local Database, while add a new person it shows the following error:

```
Failure 1 (near "Build": syntax error) on 0x29abd0 when preparing 'update event_details set total_checkin=12, checkin=7, yet_to_check=5 where event_name=Final Build Test'.
```

My original java code:

```
strQuery = "update event_details set total_checkin="+ strTotalMembers + ", checkin="+ strTotalCheckIns + ", yet_to_check="+ strYetToChecks + " where event_name=" + strTitle;

mySqlite.executeQuery(strQuery);
```

All the table columns are spelled correct. But I know why this error occurs. Please tell to come accross this problem.

Comment: Just wrap "Final Build Test" in single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
strQuery = "update event_details set total_checkin='"+ strTotalMembers + "', checkin='"+ strTotalCheckIns + "', yet_to_check='"  + strYetToChecks + "' where event_name='"+ strTitle +"'";
```

Because you need to pass all the strings in ''.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `single-quotes` around the string value(s). you should be using host variables which would take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

you should never build your query manually yourself. It is risky and opens you code for SQL injections(google that). That why you should always use some sort of API that has support for prepareStatement methods that take in queries with place holders (ussually it is qestionmark) and separatly variables. the method should for you populate place holders taking care of quotation when required, characters encoding etc.
Just example: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

I  am aure you will find more in google on that.

hope it helps